# an example of a group $G$ such that it has elements $a,b$ of order $6$ and $2$ respectively satisfying $a^3b = ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anybody give me an example of a group $G$ such that it has elements $a,b$ of order $6$ and $2$ respectively satisfying $a^3b = ba$
I came across a problem saying - "$G$ is a group. $a,b$ are two elements of $G$ such that $o(a)=6 ,o(b)=2$ and $a^3b =ba$. Then find order of $ab$." But if $a,b$ satisfy the above properties then it's eventually turning out that $a^2 = e$. 
 \begin{align*}a^3b &=ba\\
  b = a^3ba &= ba^2\\
  a^2 &= e
\end{align*}
So I think that the question is wrong. I think there does not exist any group satisfying such properties. Can anybody give me some proper justification behind this ? Or have I done any mistake ?

Comment: You did right, perhaps it should read $a^5b=ba$. That would make sense.

Comment: Hi, you have apparently confused the title field with the tags field. It is silly to write the same thing in both. It is usually better to put your question in the title (as well as in the body, of course.) I fixed it for you this time, but in the future you should do something similar.

Comment: Thanks @rschwieb .

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, such a group cannot exist (e.g. by the argument you use). A formal way to see this (though it uses tools that you might not yet have used) is to consider the formal presentation
$
\langle a,b\mid a^6=b^2=1,a^3b=ba\rangle
$
and to use a tool called coset enumeration which verifies that under these conditions the group would have order $4$ and the order of $a$ (which must divide $6$) would be $2$ only.

Answer (score 1):

You are entirely correct; if $o(a)=6$ and $o(b)=2$ and $a^3b=ba$ then
$$b=a^6b=a^3(a^3b)=a^3(ba)=(a^3b)a=(ba)a=ba^2,$$
and hence $a^2=e$, contradicting the fact that $o(a)=6$. Hence no such group exists.

Alternatively, note that the given relation is equivalent to $a^3=bab^{-1}$, which implies
$$e=a^6=(a^3)^2=(bab^{-1})^2=ba^2b^{-1},$$
and hence that $a^2=e$, again contradicting $o(a)=6$.

On the other hand, if we replace the relation $a^3b=ba$ by $a^5b=ba$ then we get a familiar group, and the exercise makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

$a^3 = bab^{-1}$ and so $a = b^2ab^{-2} = (a^3)^3 = a^9$. Thus $a^8 = 1$, a contradiction to $o(a) = 6$.